# Audio - ffmpeg produces high-pitched voices

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a big video file and I'm using ffmpeg to get a smaller one. I work with the 2-pass ratecontrol and I'm using this simple command line

```
ffmpeg -y -i file.mkv -c:v lix264 -b:v 900k -ac 2 -c:a aac -q:a 0.8 -pass 1 -f mp4 NUL && ffmpeg -i file.mkv -c:v lix264 -b:v 900k -ac 2 -c:a aac -q:a 0.8 -pass 2 out.mp4
```

Well, my problem is the following: the original video has 5.1 DTS audio. Mine has stereo but nearly all the dialogues sound high pitched. How can I fix this? Another video I have created doesn't have this problem (I used the same command line).

Also I have read that qaac does a better job with encoding. Is there any way I can use qaac with ffmpeg for the audio?

Comment: Please show the complete console output from your command. Does the original also sound high pitched? Why are you using 2-pass instead of a single pass with `-crf`?

Comment: Yes, the original does sound high pitched, but in some of the dialogue and you can barely hear it. I don't know how to copy the console output. Regarding the 2nd question: I have more control regarding the file size that way. So, if the original sound this way there's nothing I can do?

Comment: Add `-report` to your command - it will generate a log file.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard OK, I wasn't able to copy the complete console output because it's really big and it wasn't accepted when I tried to edit my question.